# Android MediaPlayer error 100 when browsing video files

Tags: android, android-service, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I have a MediaPlayer object within a service, and when something is played while I browse in the Gallery/FileManager apps for videos - then the error occurs. Any ideas?

I use android 4.4.4 on Galaxy S4 (Cyanogenmod 11 M10)

Comment: Did you searched for that MediaPlayer error code?

Comment: Yes, it says the error is about server problem, but it only happens when I stream mp3 and go into the Gallery app, the moment it loads a video the error occurs.

Comment: previews actually, not loads

Comment: What if you open other apps, like a browser? Did you tried it in other devices?

Comment: web browser cause nothing. It's something about video-media issue. Didn't try on other devices, possibly OS issue?